# Why getnameinfo with multi-thread so slow?

Tags: c++, multithreading, resolve

I want to resolve host name by calling *getnameinfo()* in Linux. To speed up the process, I use a thread pool to resolve host name.
But problem is, the speed is fast at first, then it decrease gradually. After a while, the speed is close to it in one thread. sometimes this function will takes 3 secs and all the threads look like running by order.
I was confused about this. Is there any lock mechanism in the function *getnameinfo()*?

Comment: How do threads call it, that is in which way and with what parameters? What's your DNS server?

Comment: How did you establish the time is spent in the syscall and not your own code?

Comment: the parameters is just the index of thread arrays. Each thread have a while loop. In the while block, program generate IP address randomly and call the getnameinfo() to resolve the IP. I just count the loop in all threads and print the speed every 10 seconds. Besides, my DNS server is provided by local network provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"threads running by order" strongly suggests it's your locking or request dispatching which causes this. If you think it's a lock, breaking into the debugger should easily allow you to catch the call stack at the time of the lock.

Comment: In the test program, there's no lock. I found the speed is 200-400 IP addresses per seconds with 5 threads. this is the max speed. I add the thread num to 10, 50, 100 and 200, the speed did not increase any more.

Comment: And you call 200 addresses per second _slow_ ?! I think the problem here is unrealistic expectations.